# Docker compose in Debian bullseye

Tags: networking, docker-compose, debian, pgadmin-4

I am using docker-compose, this is my environment

Linux Debian 11 (bullseye)
docker-compose v 1.29.2
ufw v 0.36

this is my daemon.json in /etc/docker

```
{
  "iptables": false,
  "dns": [
        "8.8.8.8",
        "8.8.4.4",
        "172.17.0.1"
  ]
}
```

This is my docker-compose.yml

```
version: "3.8"

services:

    pgadmin4:
        #
        #       This container runs as user 5050 and group 5050
        #
        container_name: "pgadmin4-connexx"
        restart: unless-stopped
        image: "dpage/pgadmin4:latest"

        networks:
                - leitfeld-net

        volumes:
                - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime
                - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone
                  #
                  #     This folder must have owner 5050 and group 5050
                  #     chown 5050:5050 /usr/local/pgadmin4
                  #
                - /usr/local/pgadmin4:/var/lib/pgadmin
                - /etc/ssl/certs/pgadmin4cert.pem:/certs/server.cert
                - /etc/ssl/private/pgadmin4key.pem:/certs/server.key

        ports:
                - "5050:443"

        environment:
                PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL: "xxxxxxx"
                PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD: "xxxxxxxx"
                PGADMIN_ENABLE_TLS: "True"
    php:
        container_name: "php-connexx"
        restart: unless-stopped
        image: "php:7.2-fpm"

        networks:
                - leitfeld-net

        volumes:
                - /var/www/html:/var/www/html

    natsd:
        container_name: "nats-connexx"
        restart: unless-stopped
        image: "nats:2.0.2"

        networks:
                - leitfeld-net

        volumes:
                - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime
                - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone
                - /usr/local/etc/nats.conf:/etc/nats.conf
                - /var/log/:/var/log
        ports:
                - "4222:4222"
                - "8222:8223"

        command: "-c /etc/nats.conf"

    mqttd:
        container_name: "mqtt-connexx"
        restart: unless-stopped
        image: "eclipse-mosquitto:latest"

        networks:
                - leitfeld-net

        volumes:
                - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime
                - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone
                - /usr/local/mqttd:/mosquitto
                - /usr/local/mqttd/data:/mosquitto/data
                - /var/log/mqtt:/mosquitto/log

        ports:
                - "12345:8883"

    certbot:
        container_name: "certbot-connexx"
        restart: unless-stopped
        image: "certbot/certbot"

        networks:
                - leitfeld-net

        volumes:
                - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime
                - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone
                - /usr/local/etc/letsencrypt:/etc/letsencrypt
                - /var/log/letsencrypt:/var/log/letsencrypt
                - /var/www/certbot:/var/www/certbot
                - /usr/local/sbin/renewCertificates.bash:/renewCertificates.bash

        entrypoint: "/renewCertificates.bash"

    nginx:
        container_name: "nginx-connexx"
        restart: unless-stopped
        image: "nginx:latest"

        networks:
                - leitfeld-net

        volumes:
                - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime
                - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone
                - /usr/local/etc/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
                - /usr/local/etc/nginx/sites-available:/etc/nginx/sites-available
                - /usr/local/etc/nginx/sites-enabled:/etc/nginx/sites-enabled
                - /usr/local/etc/letsencrypt/:/etc/letsencrypt
                - /var/log/nginx/:/var/log/nginx
                - /var/www/html:/var/www/html
                - /var/www/certbot:/var/www/certbot

        ports:
                - "80:80/tcp"
                - "443:443/tcp"
networks:
        leitfeld-net:
                driver: bridge
```

The problem I have is that if I try to do a `telnet xxx.xxx.xxx 5050` from external server I have the connection "hanging" and I cannot see the link active by doing `netstat -a | grep 5050` but just

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:5050            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 [::]:5050               [::]:*                  LISTEN
```

This happens also disabling ufw (`# ufw disable`).

Now it works but I do not know why, by doing a reboot of the server I still have the same problem.

Then, if I change the daemon.json and put `"iptables": false,` I restart docker service and I connect to a docker `docker exec -it --user root pgadmin4-connexx /bin/sh` I am not able to ping anything; for instance `ping 8.8.8.8` does NOT respond.

Comment: Maybe you could change the question title to match your actual problem